# ¿Cómo imprimir los resultados de un método de una clase en un JTextArea en otra clase?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber cómo hacer lo que pregunto en el título. Tengo una clase Paciente, con un método que imprime todos los datos de ese paciente. Me gustaría conseguir que en vez de por consola, o por`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` me mostrara esos resultado en un JTextArea, que está en otra clase, llamada Menu, que es la que inicia toda la interfaz gráfica.

La interfaz es asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase paciente:

```
public class Paciente implements Serializable
```

Que tiene el método:

```
public static void ConsultarByNum_Clinico(int num_expediente) {

    if (ArrayPacientes.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No hay pacientes en la lista aún, introduzca algunos");
        System.out.println("Volviendo al menú...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


    }

    Paciente resultado = null;
    for (Paciente paciente : ArrayPacientes) {
        if (paciente.num_expe_clinico == num_expediente) {
            resultado = paciente;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nombre : " + resultado.nombre + "\n" +
            "Primer apellido : " + resultado.apell1 + "\n" +
            "Segundo apellido : " + resultado.apell2 + "\n" +
            "Edad : " + resultado.edad + "\n" +
            "Alcohol : " + resultado.alcohol + "\n" +
            "Fumador : " + resultado.fumador +"\n" +
            "Número de expediente clínico : " + resultado.num_expe_clinico + "\n" +
            "Diagnóstico : " + resultado.HistorialClinico + "\n" +
            "Tratamiento : " + resultado.tratamiento);


        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el paciente");
```

Como veis, tal y como lo tengo ahora, se imprime en un `JOptionPane`, pero no es lo que quiero.

**¿Qué necesito?**

Imprimir todo lo de `resultado.nombre`, `resultado.edad` etc etc pero en el textarea.

Dicho textarea esta en la clase `Menu()`

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener
```

Y dentro de lo anterior tengo declarado el textarea.

Gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu clase Menu tiene los getters y setters necesarios para acceder al textArea, es muy fácil hacer lo que dices.

En tu clase menu

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener
  private JTextArea ta= new JTextArea();
  ....//Todo lo que haga tu clase
 public void setTa(string valor){
   ta.setText(valor);
 }
 public JTextArea getTa(){
   return ta;
 }
```

entonces solamente en donde quieras definir lo que va en ese textArea y desde tu instancia de la clase menu llamas ese método.

```
miClaseMenu.setTa("Aqui pones todo lo que necesites :) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

que tal?

Mira no se  si sera de las mejores maneras para hacerlo, pero
puedes crear un metodo static en la clase Menu que reciba como parametro un String que tu mandas desde la clase donde tienes tu informacion.

Quedaria algo como esto (en la clase Menu):

```
public static void RecibirDatos (String datos){ }
```

Y tu lo llamarias  asi desde tu otra clase:

```
Menu.RecibirDatos(String datos);
```

Espero que te haya podido ayudar

Saludos

Comment: Hola, el problema con esto es que si no esta cargada aún la interface, dara un error de ejecución, por que el objeto JTextArea no esta inicializado.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero por lo que veo es una interfaz principal, asi que deberia inicializarse apenas inicia el programa, en caso de que eso no suceda, aun puede instanciar la clase sin cargar la interfaz o una clase contenedora intermedia, de cualquier forma solo cambiaria la clase a la cual se le asigna el metodo public static

Answer (score 0):

Para poder imprimirlo en el TextArea solo asegúrate de que el método no sea static, así dentro del método ya puedes imprimir directamente en el TextArea

ej:

public void suma(int x, int y){

int suma = x + y;

jTextArea1.append(" la suma es: "+ suma);

}